# Connect an RDS database on a local environment

Tags: database, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

I have a Laravel 5.7 application in an Elastic Beanstalk instance over AWS, and I use Ubuntu in my local with a connection to the database via command line and artisan tinker.

Both in local and on the cloud everything work, the database is connected successfully and allow me to log-in and log-out.

Now, I would like to actually see the inside of my DB and do some query from my local command line and maybe even use artisan tinker on the RDS database.

Can anybody explain me or redirect me to some tutorials on how do I connect aws rds to my local computer or manage the command line directly for the aws console?

Thanks

I expect to be able to connect my terminal with the RDS database used by my Elastic-Beanstalk instance or being able to see and work on a terminal on aws (if this service exists)

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this.  One would be to open your RDS instance to your local IP address.  Then, you could directly connect on the appropriate port.  Another safer and more sophisticated way would be to open an EC2 node which has access to RDS.

Comment: I am quite new to AWS and RDS, can you explain it in a step-by-step way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Connect to your EC2 instance (Beanstalk instance) via SSH.
2. Install MySQL server on your EC2 instance.
3. Refer to
   https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/
   for MySQL installation.
4. Confirm that if you have enabled MySQL port '3306' in your instance
   security group.
5. Then follow the below steps to connect to your database.

To connect to your RDS instance through CLI use the below command:

```
mysql -u [DB instance identifier] -p -h Hostname
```

where DB instance identifier is the **username of your database** and
**Hostname is the endpoint of your RDS instance**

After this command, it will ask for a password and you have to enter the password of your database.

Now you will have complete access to your database.

Comment: This is what i get: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on ... then the hostname

Comment: This answer omits the step of configuring RDS to be reachable from the outside.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please follow the steps given.

Comment: this is the command I end up using: mysql --host thisIsAnHost.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 -u username -p